# Gazebo doesn't open GUI on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ros, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to run a ROS program on Gazebo with Ubuntu 20.04 but the GUI does not open when I do the "gazebo empty.world" command. I'm running ros-noetic. Is there some setting I have to specify for Ubuntu to be able to open a GUI on my windows 10 machine? I have a good GPU on my computer.

When trying to run a more complex program, I get the error :
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 836, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient

suggesting Ubuntu can't handle the gazebo GUI

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this answer
[ROS_gui_died](https://answers.ros.org/question/365478/about-the-gazebo_gui-3-process-has-died/)

Basically error is with the graphic settings on your device, ubuntu 20.04 runs gazebo well enough.
Try running

```
$ export SVGA_VGPU10=0
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch
```

as suggested in the linked answer, for me it failed a couple of times but worked after a reboot, though takes time to load and launch preconfigured worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing gazebo

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ros-noetic-gazebo-*
```